# Linux - memory size

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

How to check *exact* amount of memory installed in server?
MemTotal from /proc/meminfo show something a bit less. I.e. I have 2097152K and meminfo says 2054348K.

I can sum all banks reported by dmidecode but it requires reboot to update - I don't like it.

Any other ideas? I'm writing test for automated provisioning in vmware environment and I want to do it right. :)

Comment: using the "top" command should show you the amount of physical memory that is available.

Comment: you can use below command to get total available memory for system at hardware level
{$ sudo dmidecode -t memory |grep -i size}

Answer (score 1):

As to why MemTotal is missing some memory: https://serverfault.com/a/219990/37681

```
 MemTotal: Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved
      bits and the kernel binary code)
```

As long as the kernel message buffer hasn't been filled with more recent events: look for a line starting with `Memory` in `dmesg`:

```
# dmesg |grep " Memory:"
[    0.000000] Memory: 8125008K/8388088K available (8546K kernel code, 1313K rwdata, 4000K rodata, 1516K init, 1316K bss, 263080K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

which shows the physical ram: `8388088K` and the *"few reserved bits and the kernel binary code"* `263080K`  and the rest is available for the applications 8125008K and what will be shown as MemTotal in /proc/meminfo.

(Later stages in the boot process will free up some additional memory, increasing MemTotal, btw `dmesg |grep Freeing`)

Comment: Yes, but dmesg doesn't say anything interesting without reboot. I have this: https://gist.github.com/khorlodemchok/5516ec017cba33a2c7d193251d627f6c Not very useful...